# Clarification on the Use of $\frac{dS}{dE} = \frac{1}{T}$ vs. $\frac{dS}{dQ} = \frac{1}{T}$ in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, reversibility

I'm currently studying thermodynamics and have encountered two expressions relating changes in entropy to temperature, but applied in seemingly different contexts:

1. $\frac{dS}{dE} = \frac{1}{T}$, often seen in statistical mechanics.
2. $\frac{dS}{dQ} = \frac{1}{T}$, used specifically for reversible processes (adiabatic, impermeable, slow relaxation time) in thermodynamics.

However, I can not understand this. For an adiabatic process $Q=0$, $\Delta E=Q-W$. Which implies  $\Delta E=-W$. Now if we use the first formula becomes $\frac{dS}{dW} = -\frac{1}{T}$ instead of $\frac{dS}{dQ} = \frac{1}{T}$. I think it's a result of my understanding of the notation but I just couldn't figure out which part is wrong.

Also, I saw that for a reversible work source, we need to have the conditions impermeable, adiabatic, and slow relaxation times. The first 2 are straightforward but I couldn't quite understand the slow relation times part. Is it related to  $\frac{dS}{dV}= -\frac{P}{T}$? In here does "slow relaxation times" imply $P=0$?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula 1 should be written as the partial derivative of entropy with respect to internal energy for constant number of particle, $N$ and volume $V$ as

$$\biggl (\frac{\delta S}{\delta E}\biggr )_{N,V}=\frac{1}{T}$$

This is the thermodynamic definition of temperature.

Formula 2 should be written as

$$dS=\frac{Q_{rev}}{T}$$

This is the definition of entropy change. While defined for a reversible transfer of heat, it applies to any process, reversible or irreversible.

> However, I can not understand this. For an adiabatic process $Q=0$,
> $\Delta E=Q-W$. Which implies  $\Delta E=-W$. Now if we use the first
> formula becomes $\frac{dS}{dW} = -\frac{1}{T}$ instead of
> $\frac{dS}{dQ} = \frac{1}{T}$. I think it's a result of my understanding of the notation but I just couldn't figure out which part is wrong.

There's nothing wrong because the first formula is for a closed system and constant volume. Therefore, $W=0$.

> Also, I saw that for a reversible work source, we need to have the
> conditions impermeable, adiabatic, and slow relaxation times. The
> first 2 are straightforward but I couldn't quite understand the slow
> relation times part.

Callan doesn't say "slow" relaxation times. He says "short" relaxation time. "Short" means the system comes back into equilibrium quickly after being perturbed. That allows a process to  be carried out more quickly and yet still be quasi-static, making the process more practical (not taking forever to carry out).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see thanks a lot for the clarification. About last part in Section 4-5 of Callen it states that "reversible work sources are defined as sysems enclosed by adiabatic impermeable walls and characterized by relaxation times sufficently short that all process are essentially quasi-static". I'm trying to understand why for reversible heat source "impermeable, adiabatic,relaxation times sufficently short" are needed. I really appreciate it if you can also include this in your answer.

Comment: @HakanAkgün Reversible work doesn’t have to be adiabatic, so I’m not sure what he means. Do you have any more context?

Comment: BTW it says reversible work source, not heat source

Comment: Let me share the whole paragraph: https://prnt.sc/VjXr97R3czY5. Yes sorry I meant reversible work source.

Comment: @HakanAkgün Ah, now I see what he mens. I will explain in a little while (have to do something else at the moment).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be waiting for it.

Comment: @HakanAkgün I have updated my answer. (Took the liberty of changing heat source to work source in your comment). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and effort. However I believe it's not about maximum work. For  adiabatic and impermeable, I've interpreted as since adiabatic dS=dq/T=0 and since impermeable(number of particles are conserved) hence dS=1/T*dN/dU=0 since dN=0. But I'm spesifically having hard time with "slow relaxation times" part. I mean with these statements I mean he tries to say entropy of the system stays the same but if you have any idea about the last part I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @HakanAkgün "I've interpreted as since adiabatic dS=dq/T=0". You've interpreted  formula 2 incorrectly. It happens often. Because a process is adiabatic doesn't mean $dS=0$. An irreversible adiabatic process generates entropy. But since entropy is a state function independent of the process, you can calculate the entropy generated by irreversible adiabatic work  by assuming any process connecting the i states and applying formula 2. And such a process will involve heat. For a great explanation of this check out the following: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your helps and the link!

Comment: @HakanAkgün I deleted my analysis of your link since I obtained a copy of his book to review the entire section. Feel free to retract your acceptance of my answer pending my further analysis.

Comment: @HakanAkgün You need to look at the next page of Callen, in particular, Fig 4.5. In any case, I have edited my answer to respond to the final question in you post. It shows the relationship between "relaxation time" and "quasi-static".